# Why is the method .hasNext() returning true?

Tags: java, iterator

In the following piece of code:

```
int i = element.getList().indexOf(element);
boolean test = element.getList().listIterator(i).hasNext();
```

**test** is returning `true`

however if I call `element.getList().size()` it returns `1`

**element** was the only thing added to the list, so when I ask for the size it does seem to be functioning properly. However `hasNext()` keeps returning `true` even though there's only one thing in the whole list.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Because you are *before* the first element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the fact that without calling `next()` on the `Iterator`, you are not consuming the only one item present.

As documentation states about `listIterator(int index)` (and it holds for the generic iterator too):

> Returns a list iterator over the elements in this list (in proper sequence), starting at the specified position in the list. **The specified index indicates the first element that would be returned by an initial call to next.** An initial call to previous would return the element with the specified index minus one.

The iterator is in a state similar to the following:

```
iterator position
v
|   element   |
```

So as you can see you `hasNext()` is right to return `true`.